# Typecasting entries of a list within a list in Python

Tags: python, list, casting

I'm looking to typecast each entry of a list that is within another list in Python.

I know `map` works for these sorts of cases:

```
list = map(int, list)
```

But this doesn't work cases such as this:

```
for entry in list:
    entry = map(int, entry)
```

The entries are typecast within the loop, but when the loop ends, somehow, each entry reverts to its original type.

Say I have a list like this: `[1, 2, 3, 4]`. I can convert each entry to a string like this: `new_list = map(str, [1, 2, 3, 4])` to give me `['1', '2', '3', '4']`. But that doesn't work with lists within another list. `[ [1, 2], [3, 4] ]` won't convert to a string using this same method.

Comment: Can you provide a few examples for input and output? It is hard to reconstruct.

Comment: Say I have a list like this: `[1, 2, 3, 4]`. I can convert each entry to a string like this: `new_list = map(str, [1, 2, 3, 4])` to give me `['1', '2', '3', '4']`.
 
But that doesn't work with lists within another list. `[ [1, 2], [3, 4] ]` won't convert to a string using this same method.

Comment: Please edit your question as comments are of limited size and have bad formatting

Comment: Isn't it very obvious? In the `for` loop `entry` will be the value of `list.next()`  and that `entry` is overwritten in next iteration. When you come out of the loop, original `list` is not modified at all. So why should that change?

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the output returned by map to list in python3.

```
>>> s = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
>>> [list(map(str,i)) for i in s]
[['1', '2', '3', '4'], ['1', '2', '3', '4']]
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are using a `for` loop , the value of the entries in `list` are copied over to the variable `entry` , hence changing entry won't work.

What I mean by above statement is , lets assume `list` is a set of memory locations, each memory location contains a `pointer` to the object , in the above case another `list` . When you do the below -

```
for entry in list:
```

entry would be a completely new memory address which would still contain the same `pointer` to the objects in the `list` . But when you do -

```
entry = map(int, entry)
```

You are changing the new memory address (and not the one inside the list) to point to a different location , this would not cause the original list entries to change.

Lets take a simple example of `lst` a list of numbers, and we try the below code on it -

```
lst = [1,2,3,4]
for n in lst:
    n = 1
```

At the end, if you print out `lst` , it would still be `[1,2,3,4]` .

Also, assuming you cannot use the below, because you have a list of lists and that `lst` is your variable -

```
lst = list(map(lst))
```

You should try something like -

```
for idx, entry in enumerate(list):
    list[idx] = list(map(int, entry))
```

Please note you should not be using `list` as variable name as that is a predefined name in python for `lists`

Comment: *"When you are using a `for` loop , the value of the entries in `list` are copied over"* - incorrect, it is the **use of `map`** that creates the copy.

Comment: What I mean't is the elements of the list and entry won't have the same address.
Lets say this in C terms , list can contains list of objects, but list would be a pointer to those objects
When using for loop , entry would again be a pointer to the same object , but the memory location where this entry would be stored (this pointer) would be stored is different, from the memory location where the values of list are stored.
Also, map may create a copy, but that is not the reason why entry = map(int, entry) is not working

Comment: Python lists **always** contain references (*"pointers"*) to other objects. Using `for entry in list` gives you references to the sublists, and you **can** mutate the original `list`'s contents via those references (e.g. if you did `entry.append(...)`. It's only when you use `map` to create a new list that you lose the link to the original. *"that is not the reason why entry = map(int, entry) is not working"* - that's **exactly** the reason why it's not working.

Comment: What I mean is assigning `entry = <something>` would not work inside a for loop . Please check my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt is failing because you are changing the value of the loop variable and not of the list.

To solve your problem you can nest your map inside another map statement.

```
>>> l = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
>>> map(lambda x: map(str,x),l )
[['1', '2'], ['3', '4']]
```

However a list comprehension is better in such cases

```
>>> [[str(j) for j in i ]for i in l]
[['1', '2'], ['3', '4']]
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you may get any format of data, sometimes single dimensional arrays vs double dimensions or maybe even much more nested lists and you'd like to convert them whether you get a simple list or highly nested lists. Try the following:

```
def convert_to_str(items):
    return [convert_to_str(s) if isinstance(s, list) else str(s) for s in items ]
```

It will work in all such scenarios. For example:

```
print(convert_to_str([1, 2, 3, 4]))
print(convert_to_str([[1,2], [3,4]]))
print(convert_to_str([[1,2, [3, 4, [5, [6, 'String!!']]]], [3,4]]))
```

Will give you the following:

```
['1', '2', '3', '4']
[['1', '2'], ['3', '4']]
[['1', '2', ['3', '4', ['5', ['6', 'String!!']]]], ['3', '4']]
```

If you don't like using function but would rather have lambdas, then try replacing  with `convert_strings`:

```
convert_strings = lambda items: [convert_to_str(s) if isinstance(s, list) else str(s) for s in items ]
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is:

```
for entry in list:
    entry[:] = map(int, entry)
```

Or:

```
list = map(lambda l: map(int, l), list)
```

Or:

```
list = [[int(n) for n in l] for l in list]
```

As to why these works but yours doesn't, you should read about Python's execution model:

- https://docs.python.org/2/reference/executionmodel.html
- http://jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/02/14/drastically-improve-your-python-understanding-pythons-execution-model/